# TopoToRaster tool execution gives exceptions with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, 3d-analyst, .net

I am trying to execute TopoToRaster tool (ArcToolbox>3D Aanalyst Tool>Raster Interpolation>Topo To Raster) in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 with .NET.

[Topo to Raster Input](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_api_ref/GP/topic1638.html)

But get exceptions.  My code is here :

```
  private ESRI.ArcGIS.Analyst3DTools.TopoToRaster InitTool(out object beginningEnvironmentValue)
    {
        _gp = new Geoprocessor { OverwriteOutput = true, AddOutputsToMap = false };

        beginningEnvironmentValue = _gp.GetEnvironmentValue("workspace");

        _gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", _workspace.PathName);
        _gp.SetEnvironmentValue("scratchWorkspace", _workspace.PathName);

        var topoToRaster = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Analyst3DTools.TopoToRaster
        {
            in_topo_features = _inputFeature,//new InputFeatureTopoToRaster() { FeatureLayer = _inputFeature.ToString(), Field = "HGL", Type = "CONTOUR" },
            out_surface_raster = _outputRaster
        };
        return topoToRaster;
    }
```

and

```
private readonly object _inputFeature;
    private readonly string _outputRaster;
```

> > _inputFeature:  is the input feature class path.<<

what is the problem of my input?

I have also tried with class of InputFeature

```
 public class InputFeatureTopoToRaster
{
    public string FeatureLayer { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what the error message is and what values the variables _inputFeature and _outputRaster hold?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that , space in input feature class directory creates problem in topoToRaster tool execution. from this link :https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51293 ...

and the "_inputFeature" is like this:

```
_inputFeature = "D:\Temp\line.shp Max_depth CONTOUR"// "shape_file_path..space..Field..space..TYPE"
```